# Active Directory Group Policy Issue after Domain Rename

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

We are using 2008 R2 windows server. Our main IT admin renamed our AD domain (example: from  aaa.com to bbb.com)

I am  now unable to update any Group Policies. In addition, in the C:\Windows\SYSVOL\staging  folder, it still shows a folder named aaa.com (old name).

My DHCP and DNS are working fine.

How can I update my domain (bbb.com) in sysvol folder with out recreating/rebuilding Active Directory.

When I try to edit the policies, I am getting the error "the system cannot find path specified"

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

One does not just go walking into Mordor.. I mean.. One does not just go changing your AD Domain name.

It's a process not to be taken lightly as there are a myriad of things that can go wrong.

All that being said, it looks like you still need to run the [gpfixup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852336%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) utility to fix the GPO's after the domain rename.

If your main IT guy was renaming domains.. he should also know (hopefully) how to fix it

Comment: +1. This was my thought as well. He probably missed this step.

Comment: Wow, a domain rename tool exists, but I always wondered if anyone would be crazy enough to use it in a production environment ;-) As Rex said,  it can have a H-U-G-E impact

Comment: If I were guessing, I'd guess the \\domain_A\sysvol\domain\domain_A\policies don't also exist in \\domain_B\sysvol\domain\domain_B\policies.  the gpfixup tool sounds like the key